# Using BeautifulSoup to grab the second part of a URL and store that text in a variable

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a list of urls that all have the same first part of the url.  All the urls have 'ingredient-disclosure' with the product category coming after seperated by a /.  I want to create a list that contains all the product categories.

So for the given url, I want to grab the text 'commercial-professional' and store it in a list that contains all the product categories.

Here is one of the urls: https://churchdwight.com/ingredient-disclosure/commercial-professional/42000024-ah-trash-can-dumpster-deodorizer.aspx

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider using a Python set to store the categories so you end up with one of each.

Try the following example that uses their index page to get possible links:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = "https://churchdwight.com/ingredient-disclosure/"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")

categories = set()
    
for a_tag in soup.find_all("a", href=True):
    url_parts = [p for p in a_tag["href"].split('/') if p]

    if len(url_parts) > 2 and url_parts[0] == "ingredient-disclosure":
        categories.update([url_parts[1]])

print("\n".join(sorted(categories)))
```

This would give you the following categories:

```
Nausea-Relief
antiperspirant-deodorant
cleaning-products
commercial-professional
cough-allergy
dental-care
depilatories
fabric-softener-sheets
feminine-hygiene
hair-care
hand-sanitizer
hemorrhoid-relief
laundry-fabric-care
nasal-care
oral-care
pain-relief
pet-care
pool-products
sexual-health
skin-care
wound-care
```

Answer (score 0):

You split the urls on the "/" character and get whatever you need from the resulting list:

```
prod_cat_list = []
url = 'https://churchdwight.com/ingredient-disclosure/commercial-professional/42000024-ah-trash-can-dumpster-deodorizer.aspx'

parts = url.split('/')
domain = parts[2]
prod_category = parts[4]

prod_cat_list.append(prod_category)

print(prod_cat_list)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.  Since I am using beautifulsoup, I have url=soup.find('a', href = re.compile("ingredient-disclosure)) and it gives me a TypeError on the line that says parts = url.split('/').  Do you know what the issue is?

Comment: I am confused, why are you using beautifulsoup to do basic string manipulation?

Comment: I'm grabbing the urls using beautifulsou because I need a bunch of urls not just one specific one.  So would I do soup.find('a').get_text()?

Comment: Try getting the link like this: soup.find('a)['href]  if there is no link i.e. it returns None then you will get an error when you try any string manipulation

Comment: I am getting a list index out of range error for domain = parts[2]

Comment: print the contents of the soup variable and see if if there is any link in the raw data, it sounds like you aren't getting the correct response from the website. It might not be serving the content in the same way it does via a browser